# Relationship between $tr(AB)$, $tr(A^2)$ and $tr(B^2)$

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, trace

Consider two positive semi-definite, symmetric matrices $A, B$ in $\mathbb{R}^{p \times p}$. I wonder how to prove $tr(AB) \leq \max\{ tr(A^2), tr(B^2) \}$. I did some simulations and it looks like $tr(AB) \leq \max\{ tr(A^2), tr(B^2) \}$ might be true, but I have trouble proving it.

I tried using the inequality $\lambda_{i+j-1}(AB) \leq \lambda_i(A) \lambda_j(B)$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq p$ such that $i + j \leq 1 + p$, where $\lambda_j(A)$ is the j-th largest eigenvalue of $A$, but it only gives $\lambda_j(AB) \leq \min\{\lambda_1(A) \lambda_j(B), \lambda_j(A) \lambda_1(B)\}$, not in terms of $\lambda_j^2(A)$ or $\lambda_j^2(B)$, which are directly related to $tr(A^2), tr(B^2)$.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $(A,B)=tr(AB^\top)$ is an inner product, you get the Cauchy-Schwarz inquality $|(A,B)| \le \sqrt{(A,A)}\sqrt{(B,B)}$.

Comment: @reuns Thank you very much! It is a very smart and concise argument.